# Rails - Error rendering 'category' model values in the index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Unable to render category name in the index view, when passing

```
<%= post.category.name %>
```

to the

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

However, when passing

```
<%= post.category %>
```

I get

```
#<Category:0x007ff5c2c20b68>
```

Within individual Show actions

```
<%= @post.category.id %>
```

works perfectly. What can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: These are very tiny, out of context code fragments. Show your loop for `<% @posts.each do |post| %>`. Inside that loop, if `<%= post.category.name %>` is indicating a `nil` class, then just replace that line with `<%= post.category.name || "Post Id #{post.id} has nil category" %>` and see what you get.

Comment: You can use the method `try` : `post.category.try(:name)` it will display the name of the category if the post has a category linked to it.

Comment: Thanks! <%= post.category.try(:name) %> worked! why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for atleast 1 post, the category is `nil`

You can avoid the error by making this change

```
<%= post.category.name if post.category %>
```

or

```
<%= post.category.try :name %>
```

Comment: Yup, one post was missing a category indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SELECT commands that are being invoked in each case, you can see it in your terminal where you run `rails s`

I suspect that for some reason, in the index controller, the categories information is not being retrieved together with the posts

If you don't know what is wrong with the SELECT commands, post both cased here together with the controller and model